# ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries was not found

Tags: c#, wpf

I have downloaded a [resource dictionary](https://gist.github.com/longzheng/2308859) for Windows 8.1 default XAML templates and styles. In my application (using v2010) I added a resource dictionary file. However, when I paste this in the dictionary file, it gives me a ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries was not found error.

[image: find the attached pic for reference]

Am I missing any dll?

Answer (score 1):

I think that ThemeDictionaries apply to Universal Windows Platform (UWP) applications only. If you are writing a standard windows WPF application, then the XML Namespace, ThemeDictionaries does not apply.

In WPF if you want to separate out your resources, then in your App.xaml you can reference them as follows:

1. Create a 'Resource' folder in your project and add WPF Resource Dictionary Files you require.
2. Add your styles to the ResourceDictionary section in each resource file e.g.

   ```
       <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="EpicLinearGradientBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0.0" EndPoint="0.5,1" Opacity="0.4">
       <GradientStop Color="LightSkyBlue" Offset="0.2" />
       <GradientStop Color="#3598db" Offset="0.5" />
   </LinearGradientBrush> </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

Finally, you need to let your application know that it needs to use the different resource files that you have created.

In the App.xaml file

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/EpicBrushes.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/EpicStyling.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

You can now reference as you would any other resource e.g. in a page.

```
 <DockPanel ZIndex="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="{DynamicResource EpicLinearGradientBrush}">
```